# GEE - Using Savitzky-Golay filter over an Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, smoothing

I'm trying to generate a smoothed MODIS(MOD11A2) time series by using the Savitzky-Golay filter.

There is this github repo https://github.com/Fernerkundung/EarthEngine_scripts/blob/master/savitzky_golay_smoothing.js, which run a simple implementation of Savitzky-Golay smoother but not fully developed as to process a whole image collection. The input data is a sample of numbers in a list format. My questions are (a) how can I extract each pixel time profile of my image collection in a list format so I can make it as input data (b) how can I iterate to the whole image extent? (c) Does anyone know another way to work with this filter in GEE?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-65.2,-33.4,-65.8,-33.2]);

// Clip
var clip = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry);
};

// Import MOD11A2
var temp = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2')
    .select(['LST_Day_1km'])
    .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2018-12-31')
    .map(clip);
```

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 5):

The script you are referring to was originally posted by Guido Lemoine to the GEE Developers Board. He since updated the script to a new version: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/A7wKQ8WMLIs/kNGt8gwQGQAJ

The new version works on an ImageCollection, so there is no need to iterate through the image pixels. In his example he uses MOD13Q1 NDVI time series, but you can adapt this to other Modis ImageCollections: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e9f4f2bb84f0bdd26ecfbea47a71885f

The relevant part of the new code:

```js
// Add predictors for SG fitting, using date difference
// We prepare for order 3 fitting, but can be adapted to lower order fitting later on
var modis_res = modis.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi).map(function(img) {
  var dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  var ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(start_date), 'hour')
  img = img.select(['NDVI', 'EVI']).divide(32768.0).set('date', dstamp)
  return img.addBands(ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(3)).toFloat().rename('t3'))
})
// Step 2: Set up Savitzky-Golay smoothing
var window_size = 9
var half_window = (window_size - 1)/2

// Define the axes of variation in the collection array.
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Set polynomial order
var order = 3
var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2', 'x3']]
var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2', 't3']

// Change to order = 2 as follows:
//var order = 2
//var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2']]
//var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2']

// Convert the collection to an array.
var array = modis_res.toArray();

// Solve 
function getLocalFit(i) {
  // Get a slice corresponding to the window_size of the SG smoother
  var subarray = array.arraySlice(imageAxis, ee.Number(i).int(), ee.Number(i).add(window_size).int())
  var predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2, 2 + order + 1)
  var response = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 1); // NDVI
  var coeff = predictors.matrixSolve(response)

  coeff = coeff.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten(coeffFlattener)
  return coeff  
}

// For the remainder, use modis_res as a list of images
modis_res = modis_res.toList(modis_res.size())
var runLength = ee.List.sequence(0, modis_res.size().subtract(window_size))

// Run the SG solver over the series, and return the smoothed image version
var sg_series = runLength.map(function(i) {
  var ref = ee.Image(modis_res.get(ee.Number(i).add(half_window)))
  return getLocalFit(i).multiply(ref.select(indepSelectors)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).copyProperties(ref)
})
```

Comment: That was really helpful! Thank you a lot.

Comment: why the `EVI` band is selected above if we are looking at NDVI? and why when EVI is taken out we get the error `List (Error) Input array has length 3 on axis 0, but 4 labels provided. earth engine`?

Comment: Let `P_1` be a given pixel and `P_2` another pixel in your ImageCollection (IC) over a time period. Then, your imageCollection would be consist of several snapshots from each pixel like so: TS_1 = [P11, P12, ..., P1N] and TS_2 = [P21, P22, ..., P2M].

In the IC they might be present like
IM = [P11, P21, P2N, P22, P2M]. i.e. the order of the images in the IC might be totally random in time and space (pixels). How do you know your code is being applied to each pixel separately?