# matrixSolve cannot solve underdetermined system. (Error code: 3)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm working with GEE in Python, processing Sentinel 1. After apply Savitzky-Golay filter, like it is applying in this answer writing by Kerste ( [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321082/gee-using-savitzky-golay-filter-over-an-image-collection#:~:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321082/gee-using-savitzky-golay-filter-over-an-image-collection#:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A)), and download the data I got a the error "Error: matrixSolve cannot solve underdetermined system. (Error code: 3)".
I could plot the data into the API. I tried with different polygons, and I got results only when the polygon has not any "hole" inside, that's mean I try with a polygon without hole and only in few cases I could get results, in all the others, I got the issue.
I already filled the nulls and I was applying the Kongdd.sysu's instructions: https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/A7wKQ8WMLIs/m/kNGt8gwQGQAJ

Here is the function that I'm using:
def apply_SG(collect, window_size=7, imageAxis=0, bandAxis=1, order=3):
'''
Apply a Savitzky-Golay filter to a time series collection (pixelwise)

```
'''
def prep_SG(img):
    #Add predictors for SG fitting, using date difference
    #We prepare for order 3 fitting, but can be adapted to lower order fitting later on
    dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
    ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(ds), 'hour')
    return img.addBands(ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant'))\
    .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t'))\
    .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2'))\
    .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(3)).toFloat().rename('t3'))\
    .set('date', dstamp)

def getLocalFit(i):
    #Get a slice corresponding to the window_size of the SG smoother
    subarray = array.arraySlice(imageAxis, ee.Number(i).int(), ee.Number(i).add(window_size).int())
    #predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2, 2 + order + 1)
    predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 1, 1 + order + 1) #Here for a one-variable case
    response = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 1)
    coeff = predictors.matrixSolve(response)
    
    coeff = coeff.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten(coeffFlattener)
    return coeff 

def apply_SG_sub(i):
    ref = ee.Image(c.get(ee.Number(i).add(ee.Number(half_window))))
    return getLocalFit(i).multiply(ref.select(indepSelectors)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).copyProperties(ref)

half_window = (window_size - 1)/2
if order == 3:
    coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2', 'x3']]
    indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2', 't3']
elif order == 2:
    coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2']]
    indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2']
    
collect_coeffs = collect.map(prep_SG)
array = collect_coeffs.toArray() #THIS STEP IS EXPENSIVE
c = collect_coeffs.toList(collect_coeffs.size())
runLength = ee.List.sequence(0, c.size().subtract(window_size))

sg_series = runLength.map(apply_SG_sub)


return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(sg_series)
```