# Extracting seasonal maximum from smoothed MODIS NDVI time series in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, modis

I am trying to extract the seasonal maximum NDVI value (01st June to 31st October) from 2000 to 2023, i.e., total 24 NDVI images. For that I have imported the MOD13A2 datasets in the Google Earth Engine code editor, and applied the Savitzky-Golay filter for smoothing the datasets. I am able to see the smoothed data points in the chart. But I am confused about how to extract the seasonal maximum NDVI images for each year from the smoothed dataset. I have used the below code for filtering, which I obtained from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321082/gee-using-savitzky-golay-filter-over-an-image-collection).

```
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/nmsheiari223/assets/Jh_GCS');

var start_date = '2000-01-01'
var end_date = '2023-12-31'  // the Future

// Add predictors for SG fitting, using date difference
// We prepare for order 3 fitting, but can be adapted to lower order fitting later on
var modis_res = modis.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi).map(function(img) {
  var dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  var ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(start_date), 'hour')
  img = img.select(['NDVI', 'EVI']).divide(32768.0).set('date', dstamp)
  return img.addBands(ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(3)).toFloat().rename('t3'))
})
// Step 2: Set up Savitzky-Golay smoothing
var window_size = 9
var half_window = (window_size - 1)/2

// Define the axes of variation in the collection array.
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Set polynomial order
var order = 3
var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2', 'x3']]
var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2', 't3']

// Change to order = 2 as follows:
//var order = 2
//var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2']]
//var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2']

// Convert the collection to an array.
var array = modis_res.toArray();

// Solve 
function getLocalFit(i) {
  // Get a slice corresponding to the window_size of the SG smoother
  var subarray = array.arraySlice(imageAxis, ee.Number(i).int(), ee.Number(i).add(window_size).int())
  var predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2, 2 + order + 1)
  var response = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 1); // NDVI
  var coeff = predictors.matrixSolve(response)

  coeff = coeff.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten(coeffFlattener)
  return coeff  
}

// For the remainder, use modis_res as a list of images
modis_res = modis_res.toList(modis_res.size())
var runLength = ee.List.sequence(0, modis_res.size().subtract(window_size))

// Run the SG solver over the series, and return the smoothed image version
var sg_series = runLength.map(function(i) {
  var ref = ee.Image(modis_res.get(ee.Number(i).add(half_window)))
  return getLocalFit(i).multiply(ref.select(indepSelectors)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).copyProperties(ref)
})

//print(sg_series)
// Part 3: Generate some output

// 3A. Get an example original image and its SG-ed version
var NDVI = (ee.Image(modis_res.get(41)).select('NDVI'))
var NDVIsg = (ee.Image(sg_series.get(41-half_window)))  // half-window difference in index

// Create a colour composite of the image (RED) 
// compared to its Savitzky-Golayed self (GREEN)
// and the difference between the 2 (BLUE)
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(NDVI).addBands(NDVIsg).addBands(ee.Image(NDVI).subtract(NDVIsg)).clip(aoi), 
  {min: [0, 0, -0.5], max: [1, 1, 0.5]}, 'RGB = NDVI-sgNDVI-diff')

// 3B. Now get a profile for a buffered point. 
// Make sure to place the point in the centre of a homogenous area (reduces noise) 
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(84.042, 24.2).buffer(500)

// Build a stack for all images in the collection
function stack(i1, i2)
{
  return ee.Image(i1).addBands(ee.Image(i2))
}

var s1orig = modis_res.slice(1).iterate(stack, modis_res.get(0))

var s1sged = sg_series.slice(1).iterate(stack, sg_series.get(0))

// Get samples from both series
var y = ee.Image(s1orig).select(['NDVI(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), pt,10).values()
var xlabels = ee.Image(s1orig).select(['t(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt,10).values()
var smoothy = ee.Image(s1sged).select(['sum(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), pt,10).values()

// NB: convert to dB (this actually exaggarates differences between raw points and the smooth series somewhat)
// NB2 the first and last half_window values of the smoothy are simply repeated from the start and end values
//y = y.map(function(f) { return ee.Number(f).log10().multiply(10)})
xlabels = xlabels.map(function(f) { return ee.Number(f).divide(24.0*365.25)}).sort()

//smoothy = smoothy.map(function(f) { return ee.Number(f).log10().multiply(10)})

// Chart
var yValues = ee.Array.cat([y, ee.List.repeat(smoothy.get(0), half_window).cat(smoothy).cat(ee.List.repeat(smoothy.get(-1), half_window))], 1);

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(yValues, 0, xlabels).setSeriesNames(['Raw', 'Smoothed']).setOptions(
  {
    title: 'Savitsky-Golay smoothing (order = ' + order + ', window_size = ' + window_size + ')', 
    hAxis: {title: 'Time (years after ' + start_date + ')'}, vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
    legend: null,
    series: { 
      0: { lineWidth: 0},
      1: { lineWidth: 2, pointSize: 0, color: 'red' }}
  })
print(chart)

Map.centerObject(aoi, 9)
```

[GEE - Using Savitzky-Golay filter over an Image Collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321082/gee-using-savitzky-golay-filter-over-an-image-collection)